# Php mysql Query two usernames in one row based on id from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am somewhat new to coding and have been trying to write what I thought would be a straightforward sql query. Please help :)

```
Table 1: Users
id = user idt
username = user name 

Table 2: Orders
orderid = order id
order_to = user id of person buying 
order_from = user id of person selling
oder_details = text
```

Basically I want to:

```
"Select Username(from), Username(to), order_details FROM mytables WHERE Order id = 1;"
```

And get the result as 1 row, I'm not sure how to proceed. I thought I could do this with concatenation or something... Can anyone help?

Comment: Basically I want to: `What?`

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: He's trying to join tables and get usernames defined by ids in orders table.

Comment: Just join the users table twice - once for buyers and once for sellers. You'll need to give each instance its own alias.

Comment: thanks all. I had written my original join statement wrong and then tried concatenation. I have it now. thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `JOIN` to link the tables together.

```
SELECT fu.username AS fromUser, tu.username AS toUser, o.order_details
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Users fu
ON fu.id = o.order_to
INNER JOIN Users tu
ON tu.id = o.order_from
WHERE o.orderid = '1';
```

Because you have two different users that you need the username from, you need to `JOIN` the Users table twice to get both user's usernames. Each table needs to have it's own alias `fu` and `tu` to allow MySQL to differentiate between them. The same goes for the column names in your `SELECT` statement so that when  you fetch the results with PHP, php can differentiate between the two usernames.

Comment: Thanks so much, I had tried to join but obviously my logic was flawed :) I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a `JOIN`.  This can be done with a keyword or through `WHERE` clauses.  For example,

```
SELECT * FROM Orders JOIN Users ON Orders.order_to=Users.id
```

The documentation can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html.

I'll leave it as an exercise to figure out how to `JOIN` the `order_from`.